# How to call function on shared service - SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have service:

```
module.exports = {
  functionA: function () {
    sails.log('Hello!');
  },

  functionB: function () {
    functionA();
  }
}
```

then I got an error: "countPoint is not defined"
as title, I want to call another function on shared function, but I dont now how to do. Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my bad English~

Answer (score 2):

FunctionA does not "exist" yet. Remember that it is a property from a JSON, not a function per se. Using quotes should help you understand:

```
module.exports = {
  "functionA": function () {
    sails.log('Hello!');
  },

  "functionB": function () {
    functionA(); // this is actually module.exports.functionA()
  }
}
```

Put your functions outside module.exports and reference them without ():

```
module.exports = {
  "functionA": functionA,

  "functionB": functionA
}

function functionA() {
    sails.log('Hello!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@nodeman: tks for your response. But I can not call function functionA() outside of module. Then I found a solution:

file Demo.js:

```
module.exports = {
  functionA: function () {
    sails.log('Hello!');
  },

  functionB: function () {
    Demo.functionA();
  }
}
```

by call function with file name prefix, I called function in same module.